# Let $\phi $ be the solution of $y'+iy=x$ such that $\phi(0)=2.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the following problem that says:
Let $\phi $ be the solution of $y'+iy=x$ such that $\phi(0)=2.$ Then $\phi(\pi)=?$

My Attempt: Since $\phi $ is a solution of the given ODE, therefore it will satisfy the ODE. Now, putting $y=\phi(x)$ in the ODE,we get $\phi'(x)+i \phi(x)=x$ and hence $\phi'(0)=-2i.$ But I am not sure how to progress hereon.

Comment: you might find this helpful: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+y%27%2B+a+y%3Dx

Comment: (and if that doesn't help, maybe this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+y%27%2B+i+y%3Dx%2C+y[0]%3D2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly solve this ODE as its homogenous part is $\phi'(x)+i\phi(x)=0$ has solution $Ae^{-ix}$ and a particular solution can be guessed as polynomial: $cx+d$ which gives $c+icx+id=x$ or $c=1/i,d=-1/i^2$ so so the solution is $\phi(t)=Ae^{-it}+\frac{x}{i}-\frac{1}{i^2}$. You can figure out the rest by solving for $A$ using the info given.